# "tnext" command skips to next file

Tags: ctags, tags

I'm using vim's built in helptags command to create a tags file in LaTeX. While LaTeX files are not the txt files normally used, helptags seems to work just fine, and generates an empty "tags" file and a file titled "tags_te" which is actually the tags file. I add the tags_te file with "set tags+=tags_te" and *almost* everything works perfectly. Strangely enough, it *did* work perfectly the first time, but every time thereafter, I have had the following problem.

When I search for a tag, whether using ":tag InformationTopography" or  Vim correctly navigates to the first instance of *InformationTopography*. However, entering ":tnext" takes me to the first instance of *InformationTopography* in the *next file* not to the next instance in the same file. Strangely the 'tags_te' file has all the instances listed correctly. I have tried moving the tags_te file to be the tags file, but no difference.

Comment: I'm have a hard time following: are you using `:helptags` to generate tags for a LaTeX file? Why? universal ctags does well for me with sections and their labels

Comment: Mostly because that was what I came across, but I am also manually entering tags in comments to track themes and ideas across the book. While I do want the tags file to show labels etc., I also want to be able to simply move one tag to the next. To the extent that the tag file is correct, I didn't worry about using ctags, since creating the tags file is not the problem, the navigation is. That's a long way of saying if using ctags fixes the problem, then I am happy to do that, but I suspect that it will just make a better tags file.